# Recovery of Bitlocker protected 100Gb drive on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, data-recovery, bitlocker

I have two operating systems on two different drives. One is Windows 7 and the other Windows XP 32-bit.

I used Bitlocker on a 100Gb NTFS drive on Windows 7, which Windows XP couldn't recognize.

Using Windows XP one fine day, I was in the middle of something when I tried to access this drive, I got a message that the drive needs to be formatted before use.

Poor me, I formatted the drive. :-( Windows XP couldn't recognize the encryption that's understandable. That drive was 60% used. Now I need the data badly. I tried numerous recovery software but to no avail.

Is there any way I can get my data back?

Comment: So you have a formatted encrypted drive... wow that's going to be a tough one. I don't think any software is going to be able to fix that, you may need to look into professional data recovery services.

Answer (score 0):

If you just did a Quick Format on the drive, you might be able to recover the drive using the following method:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/239322-44-recover-deleted-partition-encrypted-bitlocker#t874929

However, if you did a complete format of the drive then it is highly unlikely that you will be able to recover any data. Most recovery software assumes the drive is unencrypted and so it will only see the encrypted data as garbage or random data.

Comment: To add to the info I provided, a recovery software did recover some data. The size of the recovered folder was exactly the same as the data I lost. However, in the recovered files I found there were numerous flash files. I couldn't recognize the files by their names as they all had weird ones and all of them were video files. Some encryption, I guess.